Bazel: 'No Such Module' Error When Adding XCFramework-Based Dependency in Telegram iOS Code
To resolve the Stack Overflow formatting error, you need to format the code properly by indenting it with four spaces. Here's the correctly formatted version of your post:

Title: "Bazel: 'No Such Module' Error When Adding XCFramework-Based Dependency in Telegram iOS Code"

Body:
Hey folks!
Objective:
I'm trying to add curvelib.swift (which is XCFramework-based) to the Telegram iOS codebase using Bazel.
Here's what I've added in my WORKSPACE file:
http_archive(
    name = "curvelib.swift",
    urls = ["https://github.com/tkey/curvelib.swift/archive/refs/tags/1.0.1.zip"],
    sha256 = "913012e5543f8118a02504827f3e3d5eda788bdb43eddd0e484a402584274afc",
    build_file = "@//third-party/curvelib.swift:BUILD",
)

========================================
Issue:
When I try to build using:
bazel build //submodules/TelegramUI/SessionManager:SessionManager

I get the following error:
No Such Module 'curvelib'

========================================
Here is my BUILD file for curvelib:
apple_static_xcframework_import(
    name = "curve_secp256k1_import",
    xcframework_imports = [
        "@curvelib.swift//:curvelib.swift-1.0.1/Sources/curve_secp256k1/curve_secp256k1.xcframework",
    ],
)

swift_library(
    name = "curvelib",
    module_name = "curvelib",
    srcs = glob([
        "Sources/*.swift",
    ]),
    copts = [
        "-warnings-as-errors",
    ],
    deps = [
        "@curvelib.swift//:curve_secp256k1_import",
    ],
    visibility = [
        "//visibility:public",
    ],
)

=========================================
Problem:
Despite following the setup, I'm still getting the 'No Such Module' error during the build process. It seems that Bazel is not recognizing the module correctly. Is there something wrong in how I'm setting up the XCFramework or the BUILD file?
